# Is where a way to define a variable in the Spring Boot application.yml for a list with a default value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I am trying to create a property in my Spring Boot application that can be overridden by an environment variable.  The typical way of doing this would be like so:

```
some:
  property: ${some_property:default_value}
```

Then we use docker compose to inject environment variables into that property.  The issue I'm having is referring to lists.  I want to do that same exact concept, but with a list format in the yml.  The normal format for a list would be like this:

```
some:
  property:
    - value1
    - value2
    - value3
```

I want to make that an environment variable, with the default above.  So something like this (but... correctly):

```
some:
  property: ${some_list:[
    - defaultValue1
    - defaultValue2
    - defaultValue3
  ]}
```

Something that technically does work is if I make that property a comma delimited string and then parse it in code, but when you have a lot of really long values, having a single string with all of them can be ugly.  So is there a way to make a list Spring property a variable with a default value inside of the application.yml (so not an annotation in the java code)

Comment: Why don't you put the default values in `application.yml` and just override them with an environment variable and leave the `application.yml` alone?

Comment: does that only work if you add it to the start command?  so like -Dsome.list=comma,delimited,value ? We have a .env file that exports a bunch of environment variables and the spring boot application uses those (I believe docker compose handles the in between there, though)

Comment: "does that only work if you add it to the start command?" -  No.  It doesn't have to be added to the start command or anything else.  "so like -Dsome.list=comma,delimited,value ?" - That isn't an environment variable.  That is a JVM system property, which also works.

Comment: gotcha. turns out I didn't know the format of the spring properties was relevant, i.e. dashes instead of camelcase and all caps environment variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the defaults in application.properties :

```
some:
  property:
    - value1
    - value2
    - value3
```

To override with environment variables :

```
SOME_PROPERTY[0]=anotherValue1
SOME_PROPERTY[1]=anotherValue2
SOME_PROPERTY[2]=anotherValue3
```

Comment: awesome! didn't realize you could override like that instead of using substitution